# Details on the single points of failure in the JWST?

Tags: failure, james-webb-telescope

This [report to congress](https://www.gao.gov/assets/710/704078.pdf) says:

> Finally, nine of
>   the 50 risks currently tracked by the project are related to the more than
>   300 single points of failure aboard the observatory

Being a report for non technical people, I can't find any details on in the report and I'm struggling to find details elsewhere.

Comment: Your title says single points of failure but the body says points of failure, what are you actually asking?

Comment: Well spotted @GdD, I meant single points of failure and have edited accordingly

Comment: 300 single points of failure seems like a lot to me @Krish, considering the amount of redundancy they build in. Are there any actual sources claimed by these people, or would you consider them in the know?

Comment: Page 13 of Report to Congressional Committees titled " JAMES WEBB SPACE TELESCOPE Technical Challenges Have Caused Schedule Strain and May Increase Costs", published January 2020. link: https://www.gao.gov/assets/710/704078.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately being a report for non technical people, it seems to lack any details on the points of failure.

Comment: If you have a source please pull the relevant text out and post it in your question, also put in the link. You'll get better answers with more information in your question.

Comment: If you get lucky, perhaps asking NASA directly for "JSWT   FMEDA" might find the design documentation "Failure Modes, Effects, and Diagnostic Analysis" . It most certainly exists (as well as FMEDAs for all major components)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try asking NASA directly, but I'm not in the USA so I doubt I'll get anything through a FOI request.

Comment: @GdD 300 SPFs can mean different things according to context, e.g. a)  each one could be a loss of mission or b) a big problem that means that a significant science objective is not met or c) that performance is not as specified, perhaps just having a minor impact

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Other parts of NASA use the term FMECA (failure modes, effects, and criticality analysis), or just FMEA (failure modes and effects analysis), or fault tree (which is essentially an upside-down FMEA tree).

Comment: @DavidHammen good point.  As an engineer, most of my working life has been in "alphabet soup"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synthesising information from these ([1](https://www.gao.gov/assets/680/674309.pdf) [2](https://www.gao.gov/assets/710/704078.pdf)) reports to congress:

From the 2015 source:

> According to project officials, there are over 100 different ways that
>   a failure could occur, referred to as single point failure modes, across 
>   hundreds of individual items in the observatory. Each of these could
>   result in a loss of minimum mission objectives, and thus needs to be fully
>   tested and understood. **Nearly half of the single point failure modes
>   involve the deployment of the sunshield.**

From the 2020 source:

> The project found that certain bolts, determined to be deficient on
>   another Northrop Grumman program, were used during the
>   construction of the observatory. A study of this issue found that the
>   **bolts used did not meet specifications** and could pose a mechanical
>   strength risk. The unused bolts have been identified and isolated, but
>   501 were installed in the observatory. NASA is performing strength
>   testing to determine if the bolts are strong enough, but some of the
>   deficient bolts may need to be replaced, pending the findings of these
>   tests.
>
> The project reported in August 2019 that **grounding straps on the
>   spacecraft’s momentum flap came loose during vibration testing**. This
>   flap will act as balance against solar pressure that could cause 
>   unwanted movement of the observatory while in orbit. Observatory level vibration testing cannot begin until the flap is removed, repaired,
>   and replaced aboard the spacecraft.
>
> In September 2019, the project found that a **non-explosive actuator on
>   one of its membrane retention devices did not fire as planned**. These
>   devices, which help to unfurl the sunshield of the spacecraft, are
>   supposed to be electrically redundant, but only one of the two
>   mechanisms used to fire the actuator worked during the test. The
>   program reports that **there are approximately 180 actuators on the
>   JWST and the failure of any one of these actuators could result in the
>   total loss of JWST science mission objectives**. If the redundancy for
>   the actuators is reduced, it would have a major impact on system
>   reliability.

Comment: That last one's pretty scary.